# element intersection between multiple arrayList

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, arraylist, intersection

I'm adding and removing TAGS(strings) inside the "comment" sections of MP3 files. I am mainly relying on ArrayList to get the COMMENT string split. Now I want to find the intersection of these tags (or better to say string elements of ArrayList).

I need to know if I have chosen the right collection, also whats a best way to find these intersections ? Because a user might select 10s or 100s of songs (ArrayLists) and ask for the intersecting tag. Should I individually look for the intersecting tags of TWO ArrayLists and then use the result to look against the 3rd ArrayList and so on ? or do I need to change my data structure.

Sorry for writing an essay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compute intersections, you should almost certainly be using a `Set` rather than a `List`.  Sets are great for handling unordered collections and operations like union and intersection (with `removeAll` and `retainAll`).  They are also more efficient for answering questions like "is this element contained in the collection?"

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would I be able to find intersection of elements of multi sets and not just two ?

Comment: Yep... you just do the pairwise intersection of each set.

Comment: Oh so it would be the same as I have explained above, finding the intersection between two and then using the result with the 3rd and loop on ?

Comment: Yes, but each step would be much, *much* faster than with the ArrayList.

Comment: Thank you for all this, one more thing if you could help me with an alternative of this for SET ? 
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(comment.split(", ")));

Answer (score 0):

Use ListUtils from org.apache.commons.collections if you do not want to modify existing list.

`ListUtils.intersection(list1, list2)`